# Can user directly modify client side code and bypass checks?

Tags: reactjs, web

I am developing a react/next.js website, so I start to wonder what if the user just changes the client-side code?

for example, I fetch data from the server, if it returns ok then the user can proceed to the next page, if not then user gets an error.

In this scenario, what if the user just changes the if statement to true which would make my fetch authentication useless.

Thank you.

Comment: As part of your design the backend should never send information that a user is not authenticated to see. This might still allow someone determined enough to get to sections they aren't meant to see but they should not see any sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a client side code, user can modify any code. If you have some page with restricted access, you need to check user's cookie/token and etc. before you will grant an access to data.
That check can be done on the server.

But if you have some public page which should be displayed only in case of correct response of the server. And you worry about that user will modify something to see it in case of fail response of the server - don't care about it.

Comment: I would add my 2 cents to the second case, if you don't want a user to see a particular page, just make it so the sensitive data for that page is fetched from the server, and do the access restriction for that particular route.

Answer (score 0):

User can do is updating your script path to his own script path something like

```
<script langauge="javascript" src="clientcode.js" />
```

And after a change:

```
<script langauge="javascript" src="usercode.js" />
```

And we also have a minification process where users not able to understand your code.

And when the user tries to go to the next page you can validate in the API side whether data provided in the previous page is validated or not.

Comment: It's not absolutely true. User can modify code in developer tools of the browser and execute some actions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. He can update some global variables too. I have updated my answer after reading your's. sorry about that.